# Run Visual Studio 2008 Macro on Pre Build Event

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, macros

I have some Visual Studio Macros created in visual studio which run from the macro explorer and/or keyboard shortcuts. I would like to run these automatically on pre/post build events but see no option to do so in the project properties. Can anyone tell me if this is possible and, if so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your macro there are 4 build events you can hook into:

- OnBuildBegin 
  -- Will fire when any build operation is fired from the IDE. It fires only
  once for a full solution or
  multiproject build operation.
- OnBuildDone     -- Will fire when a build operation completes. This event fires only once for a full solution or multiproject build operation.
- OnBuildProjConfigBegin -- Will fire when a project build
  begins. This event is used to catch each project build event within a solution or multiproject build operation.
- OnBuildProjConfigDone  -- Will fire
  when a project build completes. This
  event is used to    catch the
  completion of each project build
  within a solution or multiproject
  build operation.

[Common Environment Object Model Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291100(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I don't belive it's possible. That said, you can quickly [create custom MSBuild](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/15/the-custom-msbuild-task-cookbook.aspx) tasks to do the job of the macros.